# Enhance "Border" around imported sprite

Tags: gimp, sprite

I am completely new to GIMP. I am using it, because I am currently creating my first 2D rpg in Unity. Currently I want to create some fighting sprites, for which I intend to adjust some of the sprites I bought on itch.io. I imported one of the sprites and changed the direction of the sword by flipping the selection I made. Now I want to draw some kind of "wind" or "draught" to make it look, as if the figure has swung the sword. Problem is, there is some kind of border around the figure and I cant draw anything outside of it ( I hope it is possible to see it on the screenshot):

[image]

Do you know how I can either delete or enhance this border (what is the right term for it?)?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dotted yellow and black line is the layer boundary. Essentially it means that in your example the layer that the graphic is on is smaller than the canvas size.  To fix it, do *Layer > Layer to Image Size*.  This will expand the layer to the full size of the canvas, so you can edit all the pixels.

Note that you can switch off the layer boundary dotted line, although it's not a good idea if you want to see where it is. You can toggle it on or off under *View > Show Layer Boundary*.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much!